# How to find wireless network mode in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I want to know if my wireless mode is of type b or g on windows 7. 
How do I find out?

Comment: If you have a web interface of your router, you may look around the settings and there should be an option for that.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/507250/how-to-check-wifi-networking-standard-of-current-connection

try this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you hover over the network you are connected to, a tooltip will display showing additional information about the wireless network.  *Radio Type* indicates the mode the wireless network is operating on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the wireless indicator next to the clock. Select "Open Network and Sharing Center".

In the Connections section, click on "Wireless Network Connection". A status window will open:

[image]

If it says "54 Mbps" in the Speed field, you're using G. If it says "11 Mbps", you're using B.

Comment: A correction to what @snark said. That is at what speed you are connected or what speed is max allowed. IE at a wifi hotspot it could show 1Mbps

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the original answer. You cannot solely go by 54 Mbps as being G only because N is also 54 Mbps.

This is what you can do:

Start > in search type "devmgmt.msc" > Expand "Network Adapters" > Look at your Wifi card and it should tell you...

I'll include a pic of mine for an example:

[image]

Comment: That will just tell you what type of networks your wireless card supports, not what it is currently connected to. Still, you are right, the type of network cannot be deduced from the speed - on a bad day, even N can yield 11Mbps or less. And there is a way to get G as high as 108MBps (on Netgear routers).

Comment: The problem with this is that Window's doesn't give a fig what the actual throughput is for a network. All it shows is whatever the wireless adapter's driver tells it to show. This is usually the current link rate. Why else would it so often list an 802.11n as 300 Mbps? As if ...

Comment: in cmd, try this: `netsh wlan show interfaces`