# How to check wifi networking standard of current connection

Tags: wireless-networking, router, 802.11n

Both my router and my wireless networking card support the standards 802.11a/b/g/n but as I'm only getting speeds around 30-40 Mbit/s I suspect that it's the g standard being used instead of n. Now, I'd like to verify this somehow, so my question is: Is there a way (like a network diagnistics tool or the like) to find out which standard is currently used in the communication between computer and router?

Comment: Instructions for either linux or windows would do, I have computers running Debian Wheezy, Windows XP and Windows 7

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On **Windows** (tested on Win7, should be compatible with Vista back to Windows XP):

**`netsh wlan show interfaces`**

```
C:\Users\myUser> netsh wlan show interfaces

There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : Wireless Network Connection 2
    Description            : DW1520 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
    State                  : connected
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : 802.11g         <-- the currently negotiated value
    Authentication         : WPA-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Connection mode        : Auto Connect
    Channel                : 11
    Receive rate (Mbps)    : 54
    Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 54
    Signal                 : 82%
    Profile                : xxxx

    Hosted network status  : Not started
```

---

On many **Linux** flavors (including Debian) use `iwconfig`.

Although it doesn't display a string such as "802.11n", it does display `Bit Rate:54 Mb/s` among other settings.